# How to move one page to another page in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to navigate from one page to another using `ionic 2`.

I am learning from 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

```
export class ApiDemoPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){
    alert('contr');
  }
  clickMe(){
    alert('---')
  }
}


@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="root"></ion-nav>'
})
export class ApiDemoApp {
  root = ApiDemoPage;
}

@Component({
  template: '<p>hello</p>'
})
export class secondPage {
}
```

Here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/5eDjTOtNu46liZHiuHdG?p=preview

Getting this error
**(SystemJS) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApiDemoPage: (?).(…)**

Answer (score 6):

You  want navigate from one page to another using ionic 2. It just simple. You should use NavController  and follow step by step.

- Create two pages "StartPage" and "OtherPage".
- On file StartPage.ts, you import page about and inject NavController into contructor and event navigate to other page.

For example:

```
@Component({
   template: `
   <ion-header>
     <ion-navbar>
       <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
     </ion-navbar>
   </ion-header>

   <ion-content>
     <button ion-button (click)="pushPage()">
       Go to OtherPage
     </button>
   </ion-content>
   `
})
 export class StartPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  pushPage(){
    // push another page on to the navigation stack
    // causing the nav controller to transition to the new page
    // optional data can also be passed to the pushed page.
    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);
  }
}
```

Cheer!

Comment: Is any way to use string for push navCtrl? I want to push components dynamic to ionic nav controller

Comment: i have a tablayout and i want to navigate from one tab to another. how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new page use syntax

```
ionic g page FirstPage
```

this command create folder of FirstPage in pages which include html,scss and ts file

After that import this page in app.module.ts file and also in declaration and in Entries component

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
    FirstPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage,
    FirstPage
  ]
```

then import navcontroller and ewly created page in filename.ts file (.ts file from which you want to move on another page ) and create constructor

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirstPage} from '../first-page/first - page';

constructor(public nav:NavController){

}
```

then create a function, which uses the push method to navigate to the contact page.

```
nextPage()
{
this.nav.push(FirstPage);
}
```

ANd in filename.html call function

```
<button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="nextPage()"> My First Page </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that your usage of `alert` is incorrect.

Correct way: (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#alert)

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
}

showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

But another way to just perform a quick check would be using `console.log("Enter ApiDemoPage");`